# Не могли бы Вы проверить, я правильно понимаю?

Tags: синтаксис

*Акакию Акакиевичу забралось уже за пятьдесят лет. Стало-быть, если бы он и мог назваться молодым человеком, то разве только относительно, то есть в отношении к тому, кому уже было семьдесят лет.*

Не могли бы Вы проверить, я правильно понимаю:

*если бы он и мог назваться молодым человеком* - придаточное условия

*то разве только относительно* - главное предложение (quasi "мог бы назваться молодым только относительно")?

Спасибо!

Comment: "Стало-быть" точно через дефис?

Answer (score 1):

Вы в целом понимаете правильно и с чисто грамматических позиций вполне достаточно.
Но семантика, тут не совсем обычная для современного языка.
Если можно так выразиться, то это абсолютно-условное предложение, т. е. условие придаточного необходимое и достаточное, абсолютно достаточное, оно реально и возможно, а все наполнение усилительными частицами нужно ради соблюдения стиля. Другими словами, по Гоголю получается, что **ничто, кроме указанного условия,  не мешает назвать Акакия Акакиевича молодым.**
Сейчас бы эту мысль передали куда проще. *Его можно назвать молодым человеком по отношению к человеку старше его* - или что-то подобное.
Без понимания всего этого трудно понять и тонкую иронию Гоголя.

В современном языке конструкции подобные разбираемым, используются обычно для выражения только необходимого и допустимого, возможного, но не обязательно реализуемого условия. 
*Если бы я пошел гулять в парк, то разве только на час* - совершенно не очевидно, что говорящий вообще пошел бы туда, он утверждает, что максимальное время его гипотетической прогулки - час. 
Возможно, с подобным изменением подразумеваемой семантики фразы и связаны ваши сомнения в её грамматике.

Comment: Вообще то смысл совсем обратный: Акакиевича никак нельзя назвать молодым, увы, разве только по сравнению с древним старцем. Сравните: мою машину если и можно назвать новой, то разве только по сравнению с паровозом Черепанова.

Comment: @ddbug *Вообще то смысл совсем обратный* - ОБРАТНЫЙ ЧЕМУ??? Да, я иногда страдаю витиеватостью выражений, грешен, но тут-то, вроде. ничего двусмысленного не сказал.

Comment: Обратный тому что его ничто не мешает назвать молодым (кроме какого-то там условия). Вы и имели это в виду, конечно, но из текста вашего ответа не совсем ясно.

Answer (score 0):

Акакию Акакиевичу забралось уже за пятьдесят лет. Стало-быть, если бы он и мог назваться молодым человеком, **то (мог бы называться) разве только относительно**, то есть в отношении к тому, кому уже было семьдесят лет.

Да, главное предложение является неполным, содержание восстанавливается из предыдущего текста.